# How to jump to any ViewController in another UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift

I have a project created with a storyboard. There I have many ViewControllers, connected with segues. Now I want to get from ViewController (VC in the following) A , which is embedded in a navigationController (as RootVC) and presented with a modal segue by another VC B (which is also presented by another VC C modally) to any other VC D in the storyboard (In this case the first one in the main Navigation Controller E). 
I experienced that the NavigationController hierarchy is "destroyed" by a  modal segue, and because I need the function to use push segue in VC A, I need to use a second NavigationController... I've already tried to save an instance of the destination VC D globally and then jump there with

```
    self.navigationController.popToViewController(myDestinationVC_D, animated: true)
```

But then I get an error because of a nil-optional that was unpacked.

I hope you can help me. I think the given information should be enough, but if you need more, just comment. (I hope my English is not too bad ;))
Thank you !

Comment: Hello, can you show more code pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write in objective-c but I'm sure you can convert to swift.

```
some *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"some identifier you add to a vc in the storyboard"];
```

and just push to view.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version :

```
navigationController!.pushViewController(storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View Controller Identifier") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```